# datetime php fatal error with negative time stamps

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

trying to parse may 5 1942

-872726549

```
DatTime::__construct()

Failed to parse time string (-872726549) at position 7 (4):
Unexpected character
```

The same for all daties prior 1 1 1970

december 31 1969 has the same error

I am using xampp on windows, php 5.4

this triggers the error:

```
$topv=-872726549;
$compared_time=new DateTime($topv);
```

Comment: you do know that timestamps begin at 0 and end at the max of 2 to the power of 32? timestamps are always positive integers.#

Comment: I come across the negative value by `$date=$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.date("H:i:s");
$datev=strtotime(date($date),time());`

Comment: have you read the documentation of DateTime? `public DateTime::__construct() ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )` and it also states clearly: `time:  'A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in Date and Time Formats.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the documentation you ought to do it like this:

```
$topv='1930-08-09';
$compared_time=new DateTime($topv);
```

Comment: right, it should be `$date=$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.date("H:i:s"); $datev=strtotime(date($date),time()); $datev=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datev);` and no error, thanks, it had to do with a function that would check for strpos of - and return other value instead of doing the date formatting

Comment: If you need the difference between two dates you can do that with some DateTime speciffic functions